# How do I make toggleable commands only for guild (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a question... How do I make commands that can be enabled or disable only for that guild? I've looked it up but only got commands that shut off the command for every server and for those I found that do have it, they don't have code and I'm not sure what to do. Please help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please make an honest attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: I have tried that toggle commands for turning it off entirely but that wasn't what I was going for. I didn't know what to do or where to start.

Comment: Have you tried using Cogs to load and unload the commands?

Comment: I am currently using ```@client.command``` not cogs.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this forum wondering the same thing. I figured it out. You don't even need to use cogs if you don't want too!

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def togglecommand(ctx, Toggle):
    with open("FILE HERE", "r") as f:
        toggleJson = json.load(f)


    if str(ctx.guild.id) not in toggleJson:
        toggleJson[str(ctx.guild.id)] = {}
        ToggleJson[str(ctx.guild.id)]["Toggle"] = False
        with open("SAME FILE HERE", "w") as f:
        json.dump(toggleJson, f, indent=4)

    if Toggle.lower() == "on":
        await ctx.send("`YOU TOGGLED TOGGLE ON`")

        toggleJson[str(ctx.guild.id)]["Toggle"] = True
        with open("SAME FILE HERE", "w") as f:
            json.dump(toggleJson, f, indent=4)

    elif Toggle.lower() == "off":
        await ctx.send("`YOU TOGGLED TOGGLE OFF`")
        toggleJson[str(ctx.guild.id)]["Toggle"] = False

        with open("SAME FILE HERE", "w") as f:
            json.dump(toggleJson, f, indent=4)
```

Unfortunateley, thats only for the command that actually toggles the command, now you have to put the code in for the command or commands itself. For my bot, this was an NSFW toggle, and so I had to put the following code under every nsfw command.

```
@client.command()
async def yourCommand(ctx):
    with open("SAME FILE HERE", "r") as f:
        toggleJson = json.load(f)

    if str(ctx.guild.id) not in toggleJson:
        toggleJson[str(ctx.guild.id)] = {}
        toggleJson[str(ctx.guild.id)]["Toggle"] = False

        with open("SAME FILE HERE", "w") as f:
            json.dump(toggleJson, f, indent=4)

        if toggleJson[str(ctx.guild.id)]["Toggle"] == False:
            await ctx.reply("`Toggle Not Enabled in this guild.`")

        elif toggleJson[str(ctx.guild.id)]["Toggle"] == True:
            #YOUR CODE HERE!!!
```

I Seriously hope this helps someone!